# Холивар: что за слово?

Tags: этимология, интернет

Здравствуйте!
В интернете сейчас всевозможные ругачки называют "холиварами". Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за слово и откуда оно взялось?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ЧТО ТАКОЕ ХОЛИВАР
http://gamestop20.ru/threads/Холивары-заслуживают-ли-они-вашего-внимания.6/

Модное слово «холивар» от holywar  в переводе с английского языка означает «священная война». Такое название не случайно, ведь холивар в сленге современных пользователей интернета обозначает бессмысленный, непрекращающийся спор. Как правило, такой спор может длиться вечно. Зачастую форумы и блоги даже вовсе запрещают поднимать подобные холиварные темы.

ПРИМЕРЫ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ

Летопись МИФИ   http://live.mephist.ru/show/words/wid/321124
Слово «холивар» впервые сказано пользователем ChuMaster 02.06.2007 в 21:47 и с тех пор употреблялось 94 раза.

Прошу только не разводить холивар а подсказать какой дистрибутив лучше подходит.
Потом ещё был какой-то исторический холивар. Да ладно, свернули этот холивар. Вообще этот холивар не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Это транслитерация от английского "Holy war", буквально "священная война". Термин из зарубежных форумов. Обозначает острую, бескомпромиссную дискуссию на форуме, спор непримиримых оппонентов. Для каждого оппонента предмет спора обычно затрагивает что-то существенное или дорогое, то, что он любит, и во что верит, поэтому не может адекватно оценить его отрицательные стороны. Такая полемика ни к чему не приводит, лишь имеет тенденцию перерастать в выяснение отношений.